# Mixed up default and named imports

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to use the Camera with React Native but it seems that my imports are messed up and I can't figure out why.
Based on similar posts it seems that the export from the Camera is not properly done but I don't want to modify the react-native-camera source code.

I tried to import both

```
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
```

and

```
import {Camera} from 'react-native-camera';
```

but I get the same error:

**Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

Any idea how to fix that? 
I would still like to use react-native-camera library and not edit it.

Thank you for any piece of advice!

Comment: Where are you seeing documentation that suggests `Camera` is a component exported by `react-native-camera`? I'm not able to find this documentation.

Comment: I kept having this issue testing a package development in NextJS + React Native Web, I tried everything and my import wouldn't work. I happened that package remain the same version after npm pack in dev, and nextjs didn't replace the cache from old codes. Once I cleared the `.next` directory, it worked normally.

Answer (score 3):

```
export { RNCamera, FaceDetector };
```

this is from react-native-camera,it has no default export so both of your imports won't working

may be you're looking for

```
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
```

Comment: If you desperately to name it `Camera`for whatever reason you can do: `import { RNCamera as Camera } 'react-native-camera';
`